# Accessibility of static data members in an exported class (DLL)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

Suppose I have this class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
  public:
    static int Bar;
    static MyOtherClass Foo;
  private:
    static int OtherStuff;
};
```

I have some questions (I'm using an MSVC compiler):

1. Will the static member "Bar" be accessible to clients that import this class?
2. Will the static member "OtherStuff" also be exported? If not, is this due to the access modifier, `private:`?
3. If the class `MyOtherClass` is not defined with `__declspec(dllexport)`, I believe this means warning `C4251` will be issued by the MSVC compiler, but does this mean that variable `Foo` will not be accessible to clients that import this class?

I'm basically just running various scenarios through my mind, trying to figure out what is and what isn't exported (and thus inaccessible) in a DLL class interface in terms of static data members only.

Comment: You might want to construct a test DLL, then run dumpbin /exports on it - this will tell you for certain what is happening.

Comment: @Bukes is there some way I can use Dependency Walker instead for checking?

Comment: The exports pane in the current version of Dependency Walker will show you everything exported from a DLL, including variables and classes.  You can also "Un-decorate symbols", which removes some of the name mangling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
public:
    int something;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
  public:
    static int Bar;
    static MyOtherClass Foo;
  private:
    static int OtherStuff;
};

int MyClass::Bar = 0;
MyOtherClass MyClass::Foo;
int MyClass::OtherStuff = 0;
```

I get the following in Dependency Walker:

```
class MyClass & MyClass::operator=(class MyClass const &)
int MyClass::Bar
class MyOtherClass MyClass::Foo
int MyClass::OtherStuff
```

Apparently variable `MyClass::Foo` is indeed exported, but class `MyOtherClass` is *not*. I'm not sure what happens in this case if you try to access `MyOtherClass::something` from that static variable.